# S.O.L.I.D Essentials missing points?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

*I've read so many articles about this but still I have 2 questions.*

**Question #1**   - Regarding [Dependency Inversion](http://www.remondo.net/solid-principles-csharp-dependency-inversion/) :

> It states that high-level classes should not depend on low-level
>   classes. Both should depend on abstractions. Abstractions should not
>   depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.

for example  :

```
public class BirthdayCalculator
{
    private readonly List<Birthday> _birthdays;

    public BirthdayCalculator()
    {
        _birthdays = new List<Birthday>();// <----- here is a dependency
    }
...
```

The fix : put it in a ctor.

```
public class BirthdayCalculator
{
    private readonly IList<Birthday> _birthdays;

    public BirthdayCalculator(IList<Birthday> birthdays) 
    {
        _birthdays = birthdays;
    }
```

- If it will be in ctor - I'll have to send it each and every time I use the class. So I will have to keep it when calling the `BirthdayCalculator` class. it it ok to do it like that ?
- I can argue that , after the fix , still  - `IList<Birthday> _birthdays` should not by there ( the `Birthday` in `IList`) - but it should be as `IList<IBirthday>`. Am I right ?

**Question #2**   - Regarding [Liskov Substitution](http://www.remondo.net/solid-principles-csharp-liskov-substitution/) :

> derived classes must be substitutable for their base classes

or more accurate :

> Let q(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then q(y)
>   should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

*(already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735137/liskov-substitution-principle-no-overriding-virtual-methods) )*

example  :

```
public abstract class Account
{
     public abstract void Deposit(double amount);
}
```

I have a class :

```
public class CheckingAccount : Account
{
     public override void Deposit(double amount)
    {    ...
        _currentBalance += amount;
    }
}
```

and the bank wants to open a Mortgage account  - so  :

```
public class MortgageAccount : Account
{

    public override void Deposit(double amount)
    {
        _currentBalance -= amount; //<-----notice the minus
    }
}
```

The problem arises when there is a function which accepts mortage as  `Account` and do deposit.

```
public class Bank
{
    public void ReceiveMoney(Account account, double amount)
    {
        double oldBalance = account.CurrentBalance;
        account.Deposit(amount); //oopssss?????
    }
}
```

so here  , it violates the LSP.

**But**  I don't understand.

every overridden method will do different code when overridden so it will *never* be *100%* replaceable !

the definition did NOT talk about " logic should continue as in base class ( always deposit(add) positive numbers)"

example:

What if both `CheckingAccount`  class and `MortgageAccount`  class were depositing positive numbers but `MortgageAccount`  also log to db ? does it still breaks LSP ? What is the boundry for breaks/not-brakes LSP ?

the definition should define whatis that boundry. and it isn't saying anything about it.

what am i missing ?

Comment: I think the LSP example is off for two reasons. 1) There is no base functionality, since it's abstract. `Checking` and `Mortgage` are separate branches on the hierarchy and make no guarantee that they implement the same thing for `Deposit`, they simply guarantee that they implement `Deposit`. `Checking` and `Mortgage` don't replace each other, but can replace `Account`. 2) The actual accounting behind `Mortgage` probably uses `+=` and yet another component simply converts the _negative_ balance in the account to a positive number when displayed in a UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LSP says that any promises the base class makes, subclasses must also make.  In the Account case, yes, that means `Deposit` *subtracting* from a Mortgage's balance is rather messed up.  One workaround for this would be if you consider the balance to be the difference between the amount the customer owes you and how much you owe him.  (I'm about 54% sure that's the original meaning of "balance" anyway.)  A positive balance might mean the customer *has* money, while a negative one might mean he *owes* money.  If you can't resolve it so that you can treat the two accounts similarly, then they should not be related -- or at least, the "Deposit" method should not be defined on the base class.

As far as DIP, what it doesn't really mention is that it's not meant to apply to every line of code.  Eventually you *have* to have a concrete class somewhere.  The point is to limit reliance on the specifics of those concrete classes to sections of code that absolutely *have* to know about them, and keeping the number and size of those sections as small as possible.  That means using as generic an interface as you can get away with, as much as you can.  For example, if you don't need all the guarantees that `List` makes (order of enumeration, presence of duplicates, nulls, etc), then you might declare `_birthdays` as an `IEnumerable` instead.  If the constructor is the only thing that knows that your IEnumerable is actually a List, then you're more-or-less adhering to the principle.

(Be warned, though: this doesn't mean you can adhere to DIP by simply declaring everything as an `Object` and downcasting as needed.  Downcasting itself could be considered a violation of DIP, as you're no longer relying on the interface you've been provided; you're trying to get a more specific one.)

Comment: What about the situation where they will both deposit positive numbers  but one will also log to DB. is that also breaks LSP ? when overriden it is always to run different code ! please explain this point.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's not really an issue.  LSP doesn't really say anything about behaviors that the base class *doesn't* exhibit; absent any promise not to provide them, a subclass can provide additional behavior. For example, if for some boneheaded reason it's specified that `Deposit` never logs anything, *then* you'd be violating LSP if one did log. But absent that specification, you're probably OK if you log *in addition* to all the other stuff that the base class's `Deposit` does. If you can treat a Derived exactly the same as a Base without anything getting wacky, LSP is likely satisfied.

Comment: so LSP is about "substitution as long as the **pre-defined-must-list** remains...". what is it ? you decide. right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Mostly.  You decide to a huge degree when you define the base class's contract.  But if there are rules that apply as a consequence of the behavior you've defined, or the base class has its own base class with its own rules, they apply as well.

Answer (score 2):

> If it will be in ctor - I'll have to send it each and every time I use the class. So I will have to keep it when calling the BirthdayCalculator class. it it ok to do it like that?

I would retrieve the list of birthday's once, make one `BirthdayCalculator`, and pass that around.  You should only need to instantiate a new `BirthdayCalculator` if your list of birthdays change, or if it maintains state somehow.

> I can argue that , after the fix , still - `IList<Birthday>` _birthdays should not by there ( the Birthday in IList) - but it should be as `IList<IBirthday>`. Am I right ?

This depends.  Is Birthday just a data object?  Is there any logic contained within it?  If it is just a bunch of properties / fields, then an interface is overkill.

If Birthday does have logic, then I would go with `IEnumerable<IBirthday>`.  `List<Birthday>` is not assignable to `IList<IBirthday>`, so you could have issues there.  If you don't need to manipulate it, stick with `IEnumerable`.

---

Regarding your second question, the only thing I have a problem with is your naming convention.  You don't make deposits to a Mortage.  I think if you were to rename that method it might make more sense.

Also, a checking account and a mortage account are two very different animals.  One is a deposit account, where as the other is a loan.  I would be very careful with trying to use them interchangeably.

**Edit**

Others have noted that you could make `_currentBalance` in `MortageAccount` a negative value, then add to it.  If that is easier for you to understand, then go for it.  However, the internals of how a `MortageAccount` handles its balance is not important, so long as `GetBalance` or whatever method you use the check / display it, handles it properly.

Answer (score 1):

**#1**

- Yes, you will have to call that every time you create the object.  This is where [Factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) frameworks comes in handy, to remove all the plumbing you'd have to do.
- Yes, you should be using an IBirthday interface.

**#2**

Your logic is flawed here.  When you deposit money into an account you're adding money to it.  The mortgage account doesn't have money in the account (a positive balance), and you're not removing money from it by depositing.  The mortgage account has a negative balance, and depositing into the account lowers the balance (adding to a negative balance).

Comment: `"Yes, you should be using an IBirthday interface"` - That might not really be necessary.  `Birthday` sounds like it's very likely to be a value type and not an entity.  It depends on what a `Birthday` really is in this domain, what functionality it is likely to have, etc.  Even if it's a full-fledged entity model, there's often nothing wrong with depending on the domain models.  They are, after all, at the core.  As long as all of the dependency arrows point inward to the core and not outward to the details, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding LSP:
As I see it, LSP is mostly about (public) contract of a hierarchy.
You have an account (object), you can credit/debit money to it (contract). 
For mortgage account Credit will result in subtraction and Debit will result in addition.
For checking account it's the other way around.

The important thing is that given an account you can always ask it to do credit/debit actions and that all subclasses of an account object will support those operations.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Inversion:

> If it will be in ctor - I'll have to send it each and every time I use the class. So I will have to keep it when calling the `BirthdayCalculator` class. it it ok to do it like that ?

You need it not when using the object but when **constructing** the `BirthdayCalendar` object. Moving the `IList<Birthday>` to the construction interface ensures that all the dependencies of `BirthdayCalendar` are same as the dependencies of the caller (i.e., no new ones), and that's what we're trying to achieve.

> I can argue that , after the fix , still - `IList<Birthday> _birthdays` should not by there ( the `Birthday` in `IList`) - but it should be as `IList<IBirthday>`. Am I right ?

That's not related directly to the dependency inversion principle. You have offloaded the dependency to the caller and now you're asking about the details of this dependency. It might be a good idea to use `IBirthday` to access the internals of you list instead of `Birthday`, but that a question of your interfaces, unrelated to the dependency inversion.

> every overridden method will do different code when overridden so it will never be 100% replaceable !
>   the definition did NOT talk about " logic should continue as in base class ( always deposit(add) positive numbers)"
>
> example:
>   What if both `CheckingAccount` class and `MortgageAccount` class were depositing positive numbers but `MortgageAccount` also log to db ? does it still breaks `LSP` ? What is the boundry for breaks/not-brakes LSP ?
>   the definition should define whatis that boundry. and it isn't saying anything about it.

Liskov Substitution Principle is applicable to **base class vs. derived class** relation. 
Your example deals with 2 classes inheriting from a shared base, so your relation is **derived class1 vs. derived class2**. This is the exact opposite of what LSP is talking about, exactly for the reasons you mentioned - the logic is different in both derived classes. LSP is a measure for validity of the inheritance that you defined. If you can answer positively to the question *is my derived class object can be used transparently everywhere my base class object is used?*, you're not breaking the LSP. Otherwise, you are breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the first point, it's fine to use a specific low-level class as a private implementation detail of the other class; the code might be more `SOLID` if one were to say `IList<Birthday> _birthdays = new List<Birthday>;` but performance would probably be slightly better with `List<Birthday> _birthdays = new List<Birthday>`.  If you want to use `IBirthday` rather than `Birthday`, that's fine too, if you use the `IBirthday` every time you would be inclined to use `Birthday` except when invoking constructors or static methods.  Note that you'll need to be consistent in whether you use `Birthday` vs `IBirthday`, and `List<T>` vs `IList<T>`.

Note that private members need not adhere to the same rules as public members.  If a type were to accept a parameter of type `List<T>`, that would force outside code to use that type.  Switching from `List<T>` to `IList<T>` would likely require making many changes in many different assemblies, and make old versions of assemblies incompatible with new ones.  By contrast, if a class has a private member of type `List<T>` which is never shared with outside code, the effects of changing it to use `IList<T>` would be confined to within the class itself, and would have no effect upon consumers of that class.