# Liskov vs Override

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Liskov says : you can't change the super class behaviors in child class.
Override says : you can change the super class behavior in child class.

I am confuse and i don't realize which one is correct?

Thank you for answers

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), "Substitutability is a principle [...] stating that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S, without altering any of the desirable properties of the program (correctness, task performed, etc.)" So you _can_ change the behaviours in the subclass, as long as you don't "alter any of the desirable properties of the program".

Comment: There are many gaps. 1. Liskov substitution principle is a principle which means it is a Good practice to do and it is not a Rule. 2. Override is a part of langauge syntax and langauge rules, (motivated by the concept of object orientedoverriding). 3. Liskov substitution principle never says you can't override or u should not override a method. It says that any child class object should be perfect substitution for parent class object. Suppose a Parent class Animal having a method walk and child class fish, now fish can't walk so it is a bad design, avoid such design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Liskov substitution principle - no overriding/virtual methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735137/liskov-substitution-principle-no-overriding-virtual-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding is a technology. The Liskov Substitution Principle is a rule about how to use that technology. Many programming languages say you *can* override a method in a child-class, but Barbara Liskov says that you probably *shouldn't* in most cases.

Keep in mind that the Lisokv Substitution Principle does not say that you must **never** use override. You just should not use it in a way which causes code intended to work with your base class to not work anymore if it has to work with your child class instead. So if you override a method, you need to ensure that your override still fulfills the [*contract*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) of the original method.